# Redirect parallel process bash script output to individual log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, centos

I have a requirement, where i need to pass multiple arguments to the script to trigger parallel process for each argument. Now i need to capture each process output in the separate log file.

```
for arg in test_{01..05} ; do bash test.sh "$arg" & done
```

Above piece of code can only give parallel processing for the input arguments. I tried with `exec > >(tee "/path/of/log/$arg_file`date +%Y%m%d%H`.log") 2>&1` and it was able to create single log file name with just date with empty output. Can someone suggest whats going wrong here or if there is any best way other than using `parallel package`

Comment: Soo... `for arg in test_{01..05} ; do bash test.sh "$arg"  > "/path/of/lot/$arg.log" & done`?

Comment: Thanks. I need output in `$arg_`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H`.log` format. If i remove date*, it will. But i need date part too :-)

Comment: I do not understand. So output it in that format. Something stopping you? Note: using backticks \`\` [is discouraged](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete). Use `$(...)` instead.

Comment: Sorry.. output file name should have arg and date. If i use "$arg_`date +\%Y\%m\%d\%H`.log" it is creating a file with just date without arg

Comment: Then just add it to the name of the output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
data_part=$(date +%Y%m%d%H)
for arg in test_{01..05} ; do bash test.sh "$arg" > "/path/to/log/${arg}_${data_part}.log" & done
```

> If i use "$arg_date +%Y%m%d%H.log" it is creating a file with just date without arg

Yes, because `$arg_` is parsed as a variable name

```
arg_=blabla
echo "$arg_"     # will print blabla
echo "${arg_}"   # equal to the above
```

To separate `_` from `arg` use braces `"${arg}_"` would expand variable `arg` and add string `_`.

Comment: Dang it!!! .. it never strikes me to add date part as arg too. Thanks for the help @KamilCuk :-)